# AntSecurityException when opening ant-file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

one in a while eclipse refuses to open antfiles. The error log tells me that an `"AntSecurityException"` is the cause. The javadoc for `org.eclipse.ant.core.AntSecurityException` tells me that the exception is thrown when an ant task wants to stop the jvm. But just opening an ant build should not start any targets or tasks. The only solution is to restart eclipse.

Does someone know how to stop this rather irritating behavior of eclipse.

Regards, Jan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have never come across this exception myself. Just out of interest what version of Eclipse are you using?

I did find a solution on the web regarding this though and it is in the folding option of the Ant editor. Try disabling the folding option for Ant editor by going:
Windows -> Preferences -> Ant -> Editor -> Folding tab. Uncheck 'Enable folding'

Comment: Im using version 3.5. I'll try the tip with folding - never needed it anyway ;-) Thanks

Comment: This tip works in the sense that I can open the files in the Ant editor. But, I cannot view the targets in the "Ant" view in the sidebar because its unable to parse the Ant file. (using Eclipse 3.3). Also, it still shows an error popup. Eclipse needs to be closed and killed from the "Windows Task Manager" before being restarted.

Answer (score 4):

For me disabling Folding did not solve the problem. I dig deeper and found [Bug 143416](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=143416) in Eclipse.

I could get rid of this by removing the xercesImpl.jar and xml-api.jar from the Ant installation that I used, not sure if you are facing the exact same problem or if there are multiple things that cause the exception to appear. It seems the version of xerces/xml-apis in my Ant (v. 1.7.1) interferes with the classes in Eclipse/JDK itself.

Answer (score 2):

Windows -> Preferences -> Ant -> Show error dialog when ant fails

Comment: **did not help**: after I got the error dialog after opening some build file, I turned the setting off, closed the window and opened the build file again with the same error dialog apearing :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem very often.

Now I saw a setting **`Window-> Preferences-> Ant-> Editor-> Problems-> Security Problems`**.
I set it to **`Ignore`** and 'll see if it helps. :-)

Comment: sorry ... the appearance thing was indeed unrelated and I also got another message box again with the security warning opening some build file, but **code-completion still works even after the error** (which is mysteriously broken sometimes - I am working with a quite complex import structure)!

Comment: got the **error popup** again and the **Outline View does not work anymore on this file** :-(

Comment: Ha! **But making a little change and saving it** (like adding some whitespace) makes the **Outline View work again! :-)**

Comment: got it suddenly again and again on various simple GUI events (having the Ant View open, no other files and editing some `*.txt` file and suddenly it happened) and **closing the *Debug* View** helped :-/

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse , go to workspace, delete the .metadata, start the eclipse,
only one drawback you have to do all the manual setting again